# How to pass value from json_encode to angularjs

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to display a row count from a php file in AngularJS

**php**

```
//count.php output displays 1500
echo json_encode($total);
```

**angular**

```
//navigationController.js
angular
  .module('theme.core.navigation_controller', ['theme.core.services'])
  .controller('NavigationController', ['$scope', '$location', '$timeout', function($scope, $location, $timeout) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.menu = [{
      label: 'Overview',
      iconClasses: '',
      separator: true
    }, {
      label: 'Home',
      iconClasses: 'glyphicon glyphicon-home',
      url: '#/'
    }, {
      label: 'Clients',
      iconClasses: 'glyphicon glyphicon-th-list',
      html: '<span class="badge badge-warning">**1500**</span>',
      url: '#/clients'
    }, {
      label: 'Map',
      iconClasses: 'glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker',
      url: '#/map'
    }];
```

How do I pass the count to the angularjs file and display it instead of the 1500 in the angularjs file?

Comment: I am new to this site. I tried to bold the **1500** in the code for the js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$http` and make a request to your php file and get the count.

Add this code into your controller

```
$http.get('url to count.php').then(function (count) {
   $scope.count = count
})
```

In the markup

```
<div class="bold">{{count}}</div>
```

Add this css into your css file

```
.bold {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you have a lot of backend transactions performed on the page then it is better you use angularjs services.

> Angular references : <kbd>[$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)</kbd> <kbd>[services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using a dataFactory as a service to interact between the backend PHP and the front end AngularJS

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-an-angularjs-factory-to-interact-with-a-restful-service